# Creating bulk users from a csv, also want to assign them to a group

Tags: csv

The script is for importing a list of users from a csv file and adding them to active directory:

Import-Module ActiveDirectory

Import-Csv "C:\testcsv.csv" | ForEach-Object {

$userPrincinpal = $_."samAccountName" + "@NWTC.local"

New-ADUser -Name $_.Name `

-Path $_."ParentOU" `

-SamAccountName  $_."samAccountName" `

-UserPrincipalName  $userPrincinpal `

-AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "Password1" -AsPlainText -Force) `

-ChangePasswordAtLogon $false  `

-Enabled $true

}

And this is the test csv file I have so far:

Name,samAccountName,ParentOU

Test Test1,TTest1,"OU=Business,DC=NWTC,DC=local"

Do I need to create another column for group membership? What's the best way to go about that? Groups have already been created manually

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. Determine your workflows and.user tools and then write the code. I would try a declarative approach that says what you want not what to do. Might a user already exist? Might a group not exist yet? Not sure if Desired State Configuration covers users and groups but it's the kind of thing that might be helpful.

Comment: This script creates the user, and I want to add them to a group right after they are created. I forgot to mention in the top post that the groups already exist. I'll edit the post to include that. Where would be a better place to post this sort of question?